# Cannot connect to ethernet port

Tags: ethernet

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTE. I'm trying to connect via ethernet for the first time but have had no success.

Ifconfig eth0 returns:

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr: 00:01:2e:3f:f1:a0
     inet6 addr:  fe80::201:2eff:fe3f:f1a0 Scope:Link
     UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
     RX packets:68 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
     TX packets:183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
     RX bytes:8374 (8.3 KB)  TX bytes:42944 (42.9KB)
     Interrupt:16 Base address:0x6c00
```

/etc/network/interfaces has

```
auto lo
iface lo inef loopback
```

auto eth0

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

sudo /etc/init.d/networking prints:

```
 * Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces
 * Reconfiguring network interfaces...
Failed to bring up eth0
[OK]
```